# jQuery animation lags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a lag in my jQuery animations when using the .animate() method. I've tried using the .stop() method to try to solve the problem, but to no avail. I have a set of pictures that start off screen and fall down in succession when the page loads.

The problem is that the first 4 pictures stop just above where they are supposed to, and when the 5th picture reaches this point, they all fall together the remaining amount. Any ideas? Thanks

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="row" id="sky">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0" > <img src="stars.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Stars" style="position: absolute;" > </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="treeline">

      <div id="yard" class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-0" > <img src="yard2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Yard" > </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="neighborhood">
      <div id="tallhouse" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1"> <img src="tallhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Tall House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
      <div id="greenhouse" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="greenhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Green House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
      <div id="centerhouse" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="centerhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Center House" style="position: absolute;"></div>
      <div id="italianhouse" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="italianhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Italian House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
      <div id="tealhouse" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="tealhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Teal House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #0B0B3B; 
}

#neighborhoodsky{
    min-height: 150px;
}

#neighborhood{
  margin-top: -500px;
}

#sky{
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    display: none;
}

#treeline{
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 270px;
  min-height: 30px;
  top:-3%;
}


#yard{
    margin-left: -600px;
}
```

jQuery: (at the bottom of my HTML file)

```
    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#yard').stop().animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=825px" //moves down
        });
        $('#tallhouse').stop().animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=775px" //moves down
        });
        $('#greenhouse').stop().delay(200).animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=775px" //moves down
        });
        $('#centerhouse').stop().delay(400).animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=775px" //moves down
        });
        $('#italianhouse').stop().delay(600).animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=775px" //moves down
        });
        $('#tealhouse').stop().delay(800).animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=775px" //moves down
        });
        $("#sky").stop().delay(1200).fadeIn(2000);
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you not use CSS animation keyframes for this?

Comment: Can you edit your question into a [fiddle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) please? Also, you have a spurious `</div>` inside `<div class="row" id="sky">`.

Comment: You run 7 animations at a time. This *may* be a reason. I would try to "regroup" the 5 one that make the same 775px travel under the same animation by using a class on these elements. You would then have 3 animations at a time... Should be better. Looking for CSS @keyframe is a great idea since it allows to set diferent timings to each like you do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your `#sky` element, make his `position: absolute` in css or adjust his `padding` with javascript. Now when you use jQuery `fadeIn` it changes its `display` from `none` to `block` and it gets padding, so it looks like your animation was laged, but its not.

If you cant use absolute position for `#sky`, change its style to

```
#sky {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-bottom: 80px; 
}
```

and javascript to:

```
 $("#sky").stop().delay(1200).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000);
```

Comment: @Kiberzaurus you are the (wo)man! This solved it thank you very much.